# Button onClick wrong parameter in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `ScrollView` with a `Grid Layout Group` component on the `Content` object :

[image]

My item list is inside the `Content` object and each item own a `Button` component.

I'm trying to add the `onClick` programmatically to handle a lot of objects and index with a parameter like this :

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach(Button btn in scrollViewContent.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>()) {
            btn.onClick.AddListener(() => Load(i));
            i++;
        }
```

However `onClick` I always get the last index + 1 on all item click. Here are my logs :

[image]

Until Log 44, this is the `foreach` print loop and the Log "index : 45" is the result on click.

So two question :

• Why all item click return the same index ?

• How can I get index 45 whereas the i var stopped at 44 ?

Comment: as you didnt share the code with the debug log in, its hard to know but if there are 0-44 items, after the 44th item i will be 45..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the callbacks all use the same variable.  This may seem odd since an int is a value type and must be copied.  However, the variable is captured in the local scope, resulting in the same variable being used across all callbacks.

To solve the issue, create a new local variable inside of the foreach loop.

```
var i = 0;

foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    var index = i++;

    button.onClick.AddListener(() => Load(index)); 
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you didn't know about that. new to c#